# Avoiding stacktrace disclosure when error page throws exception

Tags: tomcat

In a webapp running in Tomcat 7, I have custom error pages defined in `web.xml`, e.g.:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error/error500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

However, when because of some unexpected situation, the error page itself (being a JSF view with i18n etc) throws an exception, Tomcat seems to fall back to its generic error page displaying a stack trace and version information. Of course I'd rather not disclose this information and display something generic instead, such as a blank page.

Comment: you means your application first throws an error, and when rendering error500.xhtml it throws again an error ?

Comment: @ZNK-M: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Well, this make sense to me then. An error page is meant to run safely and inform the user that user went wrong, otherwise the server could keep generating an error page for a long time if it keeps getting an error...

Answer (score 0):

Fix your error page and make it more robust. If a custom error page throws an error Tomcat will fall back to its internal error handling.